# Correct Battery Replacement for Old Macbook Air

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, battery, charging, power

Correct Battery Replacement for Old Macbook Air

Hi there, thank you for reading :)

I have a Macbook Air 5,2 (13” mid 2012) that has a battery with over 1062 cycles and a condition of “Replace Now”, lasting no more than 20 min.

So I’m now looking for the correct battery replacement online (since it’s way cheaper, around 170 USD cheaper)  and have found various models that apparently are compatible. The odd thing is that this batteries have a lower voltage than what “System Information” says my battery has.

Here I found two models… (page in Swedish -> Google Translator)

1. https://www.teknikdelar.se/batteri-macbook-air-132012-2015-a1496
2. https://www.equipit.se/apple-batterier/13607-batteri-for-macbook-air-13-2012-2017-a1496-inkl-verktyg-0025093532351.html?utm_source=pricerunner&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=pricerunner

...they indicate a voltage of (7,3 V) and (7,6 V) respectably while the voltage in my computer, seen trough “System Information”, indicates that my battery has a
(mV: 8053 = V: 8,053) when fully charged and around (mv: 7300 = V: 7,3) when almost dry of battery.

So which one can I use?
Does the difference in voltage matter?
What should I look for when buying a battery?

I’m entirely dependent on what info you nice people can provide me and will base my decision  on it, so many thanks once again :)

Merry Christmas and Happy New Year

Kind Regards
Julian A. Llenas